# How do I know which version of Javascript I'm using?

Tags: javascript, version, version-detection

I'm just reading this documentation about Javascript 1.2, but I'm wondering which version of Javascript is being used in the most popular browsers.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_nested_functions.htm

Comment: Detect the version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340726/detect-version-of-javascript

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Wikipedia (or rather, the community *on* Wikipedia) keeps a [pretty good up-to-date list here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Version_history).

- Most browsers are on 1.5 (though they have features of later versions)
- Mozilla progresses with every dot release (they maintain the standard so that's not surprising)
- Firefox 4 is on JavaScript 1.8.5
- The other big off-the-beaten-path one is IE9  - it implements ECMAScript 5, but doesn't implement all the features of JavaScript 1.8.5 (not sure what they're calling this version of JScript, engine codenamed [Chakra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakra_(JScript_engine)), yet).

Comment: Firefox 4 (JavaScript(TM) 1.8.5) and IE9 (JScript 9) implement a lot of *ECMAScript 5* features, but consider for example [JavaScript(TM) 1.8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.8), is *full* of *non-standard* features, which aren't available on IE9 (and they are not part of the ES5 spec.), they are *Mozilla-extensions*.

Comment: @CMS - excellent point on the bits it doesn't implement, tried to improve on the above given this has bubbled to the top.

Comment: Thanks, IMO is important point to emphasize it that *JScript !==  JavaScript(TM)* and that the Mozilla's JS version numbers are almost meaningless to other implementations...

Comment: For what it's worth, it appears that Wikipedia's "pretty good up-to-date list" stopped being such around the time that this answer was provided. It doesn't appear to have been updated since ~2010...

Answer (score 101):

Click on this link to see which version your BROWSER is using: http://jsfiddle.net/Ac6CT/

You should be able filter by using script tags to each JS version.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jsver = 1.0;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.1">
  jsver = 1.1;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.2">
  jsver = 1.2;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.3">
  jsver = 1.3;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.4">
  jsver = 1.4;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.5">
  jsver = 1.5;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.6">
  jsver = 1.6;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.7">
  jsver = 1.7;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.8">
  jsver = 1.8;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.9">
  jsver = 1.9;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  alert(jsver);
</script>
```

My Chrome reports `1.7`

Blatantly stolen from: http://javascript.about.com/library/bljver.htm

Comment: What about minor releases? e.g. 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3...you see how this would get tedious.

Comment: You would be better off using feature detection.

Comment: I would assume 1.8 would run for all 1.8.x as the API wouldn't change in minor releases at all.  But that's simply an educated guess about this works.

Comment: 1.8.1 for example added native `JSON` support, 1.8.5 is up to ECMAScript 5 compliance...these are important milestones :)

Comment: So this told me Chrome was 1.7, yet has native JSON support.  Maybe the right answer to this question is more that the javascript version in a browser does not necessarily indicate very much useful information.

Comment: Mozilla support javascript up to version 1.8 but syntax is different: ```<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7"/>```

Comment: Weird part about this script is that if I drop check for 1.7 i.e. comment out <script language="Javascript1.7">jsver = 1.7;</script> then it starts reporting 1.6 as JavaScript version, similarly if I drop check for 1.6 as well its starts reporting 1.5 as JavaScript version and so on and so forth. However, if I drop all but >= 1.8 it gives no output. Does it indicates that the current version is 1.7 and as compatible with all previous versions but not newer versions i.e. 1.8 and after?

Comment: As of Date Sep 23, 2022, Chrome version - 105.0 :  Says `1.5`,  While the answer  says `1.7`Which was given in 2010. Are we here missing something

Answer (score 21):

In chrome you can find easily not only your JS version but also a flash version. All you need is to type `chrome://version/` in a command line and you will get something like this:

[image]

Comment: ha ha! That is not JS version but the version number for the V8 Engine. Also, today, in 2015 they have moved to Blink as their engine of choice

Comment: @ChristianM.Raymonds then why does my chrome v`46.0.2490.86` on November 2015 still shows `V8 4.6.85.31`?

Comment: @Savador Dali OP was asking about JS version - read JavaScript Language Version understood by the engine and not the version of the engine. Anything greater than Chrome 28 uses Blink. Please do your research.

Comment: @SalvadorDali- That's the version of V8 engine(a Javascript engine) and NOT Javascript version.

Comment: @ChristianM.Raymonds - Blink and V8 are two very different things. V8 is JS engine and Blink is web engine and Chrome uses both. They are two separate Engines for two very different things and usage of one is not mutually exclusive of other in any way.

Comment: Is there a way in Firefox to display SpiderMonker version (there is nothing in about:support)?

Answer (score 6):

Rather than finding which version you are using you can rephrase your question to "which version of ECMA script does my browser's JavaScript/JSscript engine conform to".

For IE :

```
alert(@_jscript_version);      //IE
```

Refer Squeegy's answer for non-IE versions :)

Comment: Did Squeegy change user names or delete his/her answer? There are no answers here from a user named Squeegy.

Comment: @PeterHansen: Oops, should have linked to the answer :)

Comment: and browsers do that only partially, you may find 97% of ES6, 39% of ES7, http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/, and even these tables are not quite true.

Comment: This only works if `Conditional Compilation` is turned On, so may not work 100% if you have SysAdmin that believe in "bread-crumb" security

Answer (score 2):

All of todays browsers use at least version `1.5`:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#Dialect

Concerning your tutorial site, the information there seems to be **extremely outdated**, **I beg** you to head over to MDC and read their Guide:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

You may still want to watch out for features which require version `1.6` or above, as this might give Internet Explorer some troubles.

Comment: "Your browser is outdated. Please update to a new browser." ...List browsers here...

Answer (score 1):

I decided to write a script based on the previous answers that gives you the language version inside the browser via binary search. Probably not useful but answers the question.

```
window.version=[0,0,0,0];

void async function main(){

let currentVersion = await loadVersion();
console.log(currentVersion);

}();


function tryVersion(num,i){
    
    if(i==0){
        
        return tryFirstVersion(num);
        
    }
    if(i==1){
        
        return trySecondVersion(num);
        
    }
    if(i==2){
        
        return tryThirdVersion(num);
        
    }
    if(i==3){
        
        return tryFourthVersion(num);
        
    }
    
    
}

function tryFirstVersion(num) {
    
    
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var s;
        
        s = document.createElement('script');
        s.innerHTML = 'window.version[0]='+num+';document.currentScript.onload();';
        s.setAttribute('language','Javascript'+num+'.0');
        s.onload = resolve;
        document.head.appendChild(s);
        var follow = document.createElement('script');
        follow.innerHTML = 'document.currentScript.onload();';
        follow.onload = resolve;
        document.head.appendChild(follow);
    });
}

function trySecondVersion(num) {
    
    
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var s;
        
        s = document.createElement('script');
        s.innerHTML = 'window.version[1]='+num+';document.currentScript.onload();';
        s.setAttribute('language','Javascript'+version[0]+'.'+num);
        s.onload = resolve;
        document.head.appendChild(s);
        var follow = document.createElement('script');
        follow.innerHTML = 'document.currentScript.onload();';
        follow.onload = resolve;
        document.head.appendChild(follow);
    });
}

function tryThirdVersion(num) {
    
    
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var s;
        
        s = document.createElement('script');
        s.innerHTML = 'window.version[2]='+num+';document.currentScript.onload();';
        s.setAttribute('language','Javascript'+version[0]+'.'+version[1]+'.'+num);
        s.onload = resolve;
        document.head.appendChild(s);
        var follow = document.createElement('script');
        follow.innerHTML = 'document.currentScript.onload();';
        follow.onload = resolve;
        document.head.appendChild(follow);
    });
}

function tryFourthVersion(num) {
    
    
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var s;
        
        s = document.createElement('script');
        s.innerHTML = 'window.version[3]='+num+';document.currentScript.onload();';
        s.setAttribute('language','Javascript'+version[0]+'.'+version[1]+'.'+version[2]+'.'+num);
        s.onload = resolve;
        document.head.appendChild(s);
        var follow = document.createElement('script');
        follow.innerHTML = 'document.currentScript.onload();';
        follow.onload = resolve;
        document.head.appendChild(follow);
    });
}

async function getVersion(i){
    


let upperLimit = 0;
let nextVersion = 0;
let doubling = true;
while(doubling){
nextVersion = version[i];
if(nextVersion==0){nextVersion=1;}else{nextVersion=nextVersion*2;}

await tryVersion(nextVersion,i);

    if(nextVersion > version[i]){
    
        upperLimit = nextVersion;
        doubling = false;
    
    }
}

let halving = true;
while(halving){
    
    if(upperLimit<=(version[i]+1)){
        halving=false;
    }
    nextVersion = Math.floor((version[i] + upperLimit)/2);
    await tryVersion(nextVersion,i);    
    if(nextVersion > version[i]){
        upperLimit = nextVersion;
    }
    
}

return version[i];
    
    
}


async function loadVersion(){

await getVersion(0);
await getVersion(1);
await getVersion(2);
await getVersion(3);
return version;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript 1.2 was introduced with Netscape Navigator 4 in 1997. That version number only ever had significance for Netscape browsers. For example, Microsoft's implementation (as used in Internet Explorer) is called JScript, and has its own version numbering which bears no relation to Netscape's numbering.