# Browser JavaScript version

Tags: javascript

How could I know which version of JS is running my browser?
 I'd like a simple script. 
And also that what are the main differences between 1.6 and 1.7 versions?

Comment: Those versions are a Mozilla-only thing. You should test for the existence of specific features you need instead.

Comment: You can use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340726/detecting-version-of-javascript-within-browser)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this code](http://www.docsteve.com/DocSteve/Samples/JS/js_version.html)

```
<script language="javascript">var js_version="1.0"</script>
<script language="javascript1.1">var js_version="1.1"</script>
<script language="javascript1.2">var js_version="1.2"</script>
<script language="javascript1.3">var js_version="1.3"</script>
<script language="javascript1.4">var js_version="1.4"</script>
<script language="javascript1.5">var js_version="1.5"</script>
<script language="javascript1.6">var js_version="1.6"</script>
```

And then to detect the version -

```
<script language="javascript">
  document.write(js_version); 
</script>
```

Comment: Great. Just what I needed !