# How to know Javascript version?

Tags: javascript

How to know current version of JavaScript (not JQuery) is getting used in my MVC 3 or MVC 5 in .Net Project?

As i know Chrome or IE or Firefox shows different version name but what i want to ask is how to change the version in my project that can use ECMA script version 5.1 or in near future 6?

Comment: Please refer the below answer. it might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340726/detect-version-of-javascript

Comment: It shouldn't matter what version of JavaScript is available, what should matter is what features and methods are available.

Comment: Thanks all, i have gone through given links those are useful but still i have confusion that Does javascript version and ECMA version are same? can i change it?