# How to detect ECMAscript version?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-5

I want to see what ECMAscript version I'm using in my browser(e.g,chrome 59) ,because there is some difference between ECMAscript3 and ECMAscript5 when dealing with something RegExp stuff.
I've found the relevant information about this,but I can't find a specific answer about how to detect the ECMAscript version.
Thank's in advanced.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

May be you can try to use some data structures that are specifically added in `ES6` like `Map`, `Set` etc. This is to differentiate between `ES5` and `ES6` but you can look up for features that are added in `ES5` which are not present in `ES3` in your case?

```js
try {
  var k = new Map();
  console.log("ES6 supported!!")
} catch(err) {
  console.log("ES6 not supported :(")
}

try {
  var k = new HashMap();
  console.log("ES100 supported!!")
} catch(err) {
  console.log("ES100 not supported :(")
}
```

Comment: `new` operator can only check existence of constructor/function names. More tests are better to be added to check functionalities.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think that's possible because browsers normally don't implement all features of an ECMAScript version at once. That's why we have libraries like [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com) and websites like [Can I use ...](https://caniuse.com) to find out what features can be used.

You could still build a little test that determines how RegEx in the user's browser version behaves.

Comment: Thanks for your advice:).

Answer (score 7):

ECMAScript is an industry standard:

> ECMAScript is a trademarked scripting-language specification
>   standardized by Ecma International in ECMA-262 and ISO/IEC 16262. It
>   was created to standardize JavaScript, so as to foster multiple
>   independent implementations.

Javascript is a popular implementation, more or less:

> JavaScript has remained the best-known
>   implementation of ECMAScript since the standard was first published,
>   with other well-known implementations including JScript and
>   ActionScript. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript)

Considering the current status of JavaScript implementations in various browsers, node.js etc, no one is specifically versioning themselves but keeps evolving with new features. So the best way is to detect, possibly with 3rd party libs, if the feature wanted exists and then use. Otherwise fall back to a more traditional one. Normally it's to try some operations and then check if as expected, no magic.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an extended ECMAScript detector (based off @Infigon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75325970/1298155)).

```js
var ecmaScriptInfo = (function() {
                  // () => { is not allowed
  function getESEdition() {
    var array = [];
    switch (true) {
      case !Array.isArray:
        return 3;
      case !window.Promise:
        return 5;
      case !array.includes:
        return 6;
      case !''.padStart:
        return 7;
      case !Promise.prototype.finally:
        return 8;
      case !window.BigInt:
        return 9;
      case !Promise.allSettled:
        return 10;
      case !''.replaceAll:
        return 11;
      case !array.at:
        return 12;
      default:
        return 13;
    }
  }

  function getESYear(edition) {
    return {
      3: 1999,
      5: 2009
    }[edition] || (2009 + edition); // nullish coalescing (??) is not allowed
  }
  
  var edition = getESEdition();
  var year = getESYear(edition);

  return {
    edition: edition, // usually shortened [edition,]
    year: year,       // usually shortened [year,]
    text: 'Edition: '+ edition +' | Year: '+ year
       // `Edition: ${edition} | Year: ${year}` is not allowed
  }
})();

console.log(ecmaScriptInfo.edition);
console.log(ecmaScriptInfo.year);
console.log(ecmaScriptInfo.text);
```

The additions and changes are:

- It adds a [function closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to create private functions and variables.
- It uses a [switch for better performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445067/if-vs-switch-speed).
- It fixes the incorrect year for edition 5, by the use of an [object literal](https://dev.to/b3ns44d/alternative-to-if-else-and-switch-object-literals-in-javascript-3nde), which was released 2009 (not 5 + 2009). A [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) would have been used, instead of an OR (||), but it did not exist in earlier editions.
- It returns the values as an object that can be used however one wishes to. For example, `console.log(ecmaScriptInfo.edition)`.

> **Note:**
>
> The [Arrow Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) was introduced in edition 10 (2019); hence why a standard function call was used.
>
> [Nullish Coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) was introduced in edition 11 (2020); hence why a logical OR (||) (logical disjunction) was used.
>
> Object literal shared key and value shorthand came in later editions; hence why `edition: edition` was not shortened.
>
> [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) was introduced in edition 9 (2018); hence why `Edition: ${edition} | Year: ${year}` was not used.
>
> `var` was used instead of `const` as the constant might go outside of block-scope in older browsers [[source](https://caniuse.com/const)]

Comment: It seems to work well, although https://caniuse.com/const says that the "const" keyword may actually go outside the scope, so maybe consider changing it to "var," but otherwise it works great!

Comment: Ok, fair point, and thank you for the starting point!

Answer (score 4):

Here's an extended EcmaScript detector:

```js
function getES() {
  var array = []
  if (!Array.isArray) {
    return 3
  } else if (!window.Promise) {
    return 5
  } else if (!array.includes) {
    return 6
  } else if (!"".padStart) {
    return 7
  } else if (!Promise.prototype.finally) {
    return 8
  } else if (!window.BigInt) {
    return 9
  } else if (!Promise.allSettled) {
    return 10
  } else if (!"".replaceAll) {
    return 11
  } else if (!array.at) {
    return 12
  } else if (!array.with) {
    return 13
  } else {
    return 14
  }
}

var ecmascript = getES()
var year = 1999
if (ecmascript !== 3) {
  year = ecmascript + 2009
}
console.log("Version " + ecmascript + ", Year " + year)
```

It just checks for a property that should exist in each version. However, I would only use this for maybe error logging, as you could just check for each feature.

Note that in special cases, a browser may actually have a high ES version *but* that specific feature just wasn't implemented. This shouldn't be too much of an issue though.

(ckhatton has the improved answer that should work for older versions; I have not tested this except in a shiny new browser.)

<sub>Note that `window` makes it only work in browsers, so maybe for the special case of NodeJS, try replacing it with `global`, or even *older* ones with `GLOBAL`. (This is not what the OP asked, so I'm not going into detail!)</sub>

Comment: Great @Infigon, but edition 5 was printing as the year 2014 instead of 2009. So I have used an Object Literal to solve it 

Comment: @Crimbo unfortunately I do not have the ability to test this; does it work on your end?

Comment: For some reason no one verified my edits, so you never got to see the changes. I am also not being allowed to make anymore edits, so I have created a new answer instead with the changes

Comment: Plus one for the effort

Answer (score 1):

ECMAScript support different object on each version. To detect the ECMAScript version we can check the object exits into a browser or not. If that object is identified that means ECMA Version supported into the browser.

Check the following link has a good example to detect ECMAScript Version.

https://www.devdiscuss.com/how-to-detect-the-ecmascript-version/

Comment: Can you paste the example into your answer?

Comment: @Heptite code is big, please copy from website

Comment: This looks useful.  Would you be able to update it to detect newer ECMA versions 12 and 13?