# Test Browser Compatibility for New Regular Expression Features

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind, named-captures, ecmascript-2018

What's the best practice for determining if a browser supports the [new regular expression features](https://github.com/gskinner/regexr/issues/283) specified in the ECMAScript 2018 Language Specification?

I suspect you just have to write try catch statements or do it by detecting browser versions, but thought I check here first.

Comment: There are a couple of good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47374678/how-to-detect-ecmascript-version).

Comment: I thought I might find an example test on [caniuse](https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/4704), but it doesn't seem like they're testing for named capture groups yet.