# How to upgrade es2017 to es2020 without upgrading angular version?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, upgrade, ecmascript-2017

I want to upgrade es2017 to es2020, but I don't want to upgrade angular version. Is it possible? My angular version is 5.2.

Comment: No, because that's not really how JS versions work. _"Considering the current status of JavaScript implementations in various browsers, node.js etc, no one is specifically versioning themselves but keeps evolving with new features."_ - from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47374956/989920

Comment: If you're on Angular 5 why _don't_ you want to upgrade it? The current version is 13, and nothing before 11 is supported any more.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know but is not my choice :(

Comment: Why would Angular 5.2 not work with ES2020?

Comment: Talk to the lead/management about upgrading. I recently spent 2.5 days doing an upgrade from 5 to 11. I took my time and branched each version upgrade to be safe. Fortunate for me I ran into no problems.