# How to check JavaScript version in web browser?

Tags: javascript, browser

I want to check `JavaScript Version` in my web browser.

Is `navigator` Object return proper JavaScript version?

```
navigator.appVersion;  /*Is it correct?*/
navigator.appCodeName;
navigator.appName;
```

Is there any way to detect exact `JavaScript Version` from `Browser console` or anything else?

Comment: Already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271566/how-do-i-know-which-version-of-javascript-im-using

Comment: What are you planning to do once you've detected the version, whatever that means?

Comment: I want to show warning/alert to user, If some new features of latest Javascript  version are not supported current(old) version Of Javascript in clients browser. @torazaburo

Comment: And also want to know about `navigator.appVersion;` is returning exact version of Javascript or Not. @torazaburo

Comment: Maybe this question is not 100% duplicate of that question you mentioned :( :( :( @torazaburo

Comment: What is the user supposed to do when they see the warning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Browsers don't give any real version, because they don't exactly support any one version. They support some (or most) features of some versions.

Any support declared for "JavaScript 1.x" is just [a legacy hack for compatibility with Netscape](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#scriptingLanguages).

Similarly, these `navigator` fields are useless *on purpose*. In the past they have been misused to block browsers so much, that the spec now [recommends all browsers to lie and say they are Netscape 4.0](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-navigator-appname).

On the web, in general, you should never check version of anything to decide whether it supports the features you need, because it's too easy to make an invalid assumption and break your code in some browser, including future ones you can't test now (e.g. a feature may not be related to the version you assume, or browsers may lie about versions they support in order to work around sites blocking them).

You should use [**feature detection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Feature_detection) instead.

You can detect presence of individual JavaScript features by running them and seeing if they work. If the new feature requires a new syntax, you can try running that syntax inside `eval`. See how it's done on: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ (there's a `(c)` icon with detection code next to features when you expand the list).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I updated my question. Please check.

Comment: On Chromium `chrome://version/` give the name and version of the JS Engine (V8). Is there a way in Firefox to display SpiderMonker version (there is nothing in `about:support`)?