# sort array multidimensional JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have to sort this:
I'm taking data from a db from two different `select` query and I have to sort them by `mpriority` and by `mdate`.

I know how to sort array of objects, but I cannot use `object` nor `object.key`

```
    var allocations = new Array(); 
    allocations[0] =
    [   qtA =  15,
        mdata=  '1234',
        mid =  '234234234',
        qtyToDoTemp=  11,
        mpriority=  5,
        mdate=  new Date('2017-04-27 11:26:02.147'),
    ];

allocations[1] =
    [
        qtA= 13,
        mdata=  '1234',
        mid =  '234234234',
        qtyToDoTemp= 11,
        mpriority= 5,
        mdate= new Date('2016-10-07 00:00:00.000'),
    ];

allocations[2] =
    [
        qtA= 16,
        mdata=  '1234',
        mid =  '234234234',
        qtyToDoTemp= 11,
        mpriority= 4,
        mdate= new Date('2017-04-27 11:26:02.147'),
    ];

allocations[3] =
    [
        qtA= 95,
        mdata=  '1234',
        mid =  '234234234',
        qtyToDoTemp= 11,
        mpriority= 1,
        mdate= new Date('2016-10-06 00:00:00.000'),
    ];

allocations[4] =
    [
        qtA= 75,
        mdata=  '1234',
        mid =  '234234234',
        qtyToDoTemp= 11,
        mpriority= 8,
        mdate= new Date('2017-02-20 12:41:34.903'),
    ];

allocations[5] =
    [
        qtA= 45,
        mdata=  '1234',
        mid =  '234234234',
        qtyToDoTemp= 11,
        mpriority= 0,
        mdate= new Date('2017-04-27 11:26:02.147'),
    ];
```

The sort function should look at first at `mpriority` - if two value are the same then check `mdate`

I think it would be something like this

```
var sortOptions = {
    byPriorityAndDate: function (a, b) {
        return (b.mpriority - a.mpriority) || (a.mdate - b.mdate);
    },
}
```

and how to check which version of JavaScript I'm working on?

Comment: What is the problem you encounter with your sort function? NB: (1) The syntax of your array definition is not doing what you think it does. (2) for knowing the version of JavaScript, read what the version release of your browser says about that. See also [this simple check](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4271622/5459839)

Comment: Is this pseudo-code or something? Because it looks like you're trying to create an object rather than an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you initialise your array is wrong. Although it will run without errors, it does something different than you expect.

This:

```
allocations[0] =
[   qtA =  15,
    mdata=  '1234',
    mid =  '234234234',
    qtyToDoTemp=  11,
    mpriority=  5,
    mdate=  new Date('2017-04-27 11:26:02.147'),
];
```

...will in fact assign values to global variables, like this:

```
qtA =  15,
mdata=  '1234',
mid =  '234234234',
qtyToDoTemp=  11,
mpriority=  5,
mdate=  new Date('2017-04-27 11:26:02.147')
```

And then the array will get at index 0 a nested array with the following values:

```
allocations[0] = [
    15,
    '1234',
    '234234234',
    11,
    5,
    new Date('2017-04-27 11:26:02.147'),
];
```

So, the result of your code is an array of nested arrays, not of objects.

To create an array of objects, use this syntax:

```
var allocations = [{
    qtA: 15,
    mdata:  '1234',
    mid:  '234234234',
    qtyToDoTemp:  11,
    mpriority:  5,
    mdate:  new Date('2017-04-27 11:26:02.147'),
}, {
    qtA: 13,
    mdata:  '1234',
    mid :  '234234234',
    qtyToDoTemp: 11,
    mpriority: 5,
    mdate: new Date('2016-10-07 00:00:00.000'),
}, {
    // ...etc, etc
}];
```

And now your function will work:

```js
var sortOptions = {
    byPriorityAndDate: function (a, b) {
        return (b.mpriority - a.mpriority) || (a.mdate - b.mdate);
    },
}

var allocations = [{
    qtA: 15,
    mdata:  '1234',
    mid:  '234234234',
    qtyToDoTemp:  11,
    mpriority:  5,
    mdate:  new Date('2017-04-27 11:26:02.147'),
}, {
    qtA: 13,
    mdata:  '1234',
    mid :  '234234234',
    qtyToDoTemp: 11,
    mpriority: 5,
    mdate: new Date('2016-10-07 00:00:00.000'),
}, {
    qtA: 16,
    mdata:  '1234',
    mid :  '234234234',
    qtyToDoTemp: 11,
    mpriority: 4,
    mdate: new Date('2017-04-27 11:26:02.147'),
}, {
    qtA: 95,
    mdata:  '1234',
    mid :  '234234234',
    qtyToDoTemp: 11,
    mpriority: 1,
    mdate: new Date('2016-10-06 00:00:00.000'),
}, {
    qtA: 75,
    mdata:  '1234',
    mid :  '234234234',
    qtyToDoTemp: 11,
    mpriority: 8,
    mdate: new Date('2017-02-20 12:41:34.903'),
}, {
    qtA: 45,
    mdata:  '1234',
    mid:  '234234234',
    qtyToDoTemp: 11,
    mpriority: 0,
    mdate: new Date('2017-04-27 11:26:02.147'),
}];

allocations.sort(sortOptions.byPriorityAndDate);

console.log(allocations);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have array of arrays, not of objects.

I suggest you to convert your array of arrays in an array of objects, instantiating every element like this:

```
allocations[0] = {
    qtA:  15,
    mdata:  '1234',
    mid:  '234234234',
    qtyToDoTemp:  11,
    mpriority:  5,
    mdate:  new Date('2017-04-27 11:26:02.147'),
};
```

In this way the function you have written for comparison should work

Also, I suggest you to read [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript) to have an idea of which kind of comparison you want

Anyway, this sort function will work for your case:

```
allocations = allocations.sort((a, b) => {
   if (a[4] === b[4]) {
        return a[5].getTime() - b[5].getTime();
   }

   return a[4] - b[4];
})
```

```js
var allocations = new Array(); 
    allocations[0] =
    [   qtA =  15,
        mdata=  '1234',
        mid =  '234234234',
        qtyToDoTemp=  11,
        mpriority=  5,
        mdate=  new Date('2017-04-27 11:26:02.147'),
    ];

allocations[1] =
    [
        qtA= 13,
        mdata=  '1234',
        mid =  '234234234',
        qtyToDoTemp= 11,
        mpriority= 5,
        mdate= new Date('2016-10-07 00:00:00.000'),
    ];

allocations[2] =
    [
        qtA= 16,
        mdata=  '1234',
        mid =  '234234234',
        qtyToDoTemp= 11,
        mpriority= 4,
        mdate= new Date('2017-04-27 11:26:02.147'),
    ];

allocations[3] =
    [
        qtA= 95,
        mdata=  '1234',
        mid =  '234234234',
        qtyToDoTemp= 11,
        mpriority= 1,
        mdate= new Date('2016-10-06 00:00:00.000'),
    ];

allocations[4] =
    [
        qtA= 75,
        mdata=  '1234',
        mid =  '234234234',
        qtyToDoTemp= 11,
        mpriority= 8,
        mdate= new Date('2017-02-20 12:41:34.903'),
    ];

allocations[5] =
    [
        qtA= 45,
        mdata=  '1234',
        mid =  '234234234',
        qtyToDoTemp= 11,
        mpriority= 0,
        mdate= new Date('2017-04-27 11:26:02.147'),
    ];

allocations = allocations.sort((a, b) => {
   if (a[4] === b[4]) {
        return a[5].getTime() - b[5].getTime();
   }
   
   return a[4] - b[4];
})

console.log(allocations)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, here I've rewritten your code so that it does what I **think** you want it to do:

```
var allocations = []; 
allocations.push({
  qtA: 15,
  mdata: '1234',
  mid: '234234234',
  qtyToDoTemp: 11,
  mpriority: 5,
  mdate: new Date('2017-04-27 11:26:02.147')
});

allocations.push({
  qtA: 13,
  mdata: '1234',
  mid: '234234234',
  qtyToDoTemp: 11,
  mpriority: 5,
  mdate: new Date('2016-10-07 00:00:00.000')
});

allocations.push({
  qtA: 16,
  mdata: '1234',
  mid: '234234234',
  qtyToDoTemp: 11,
  mpriority: 4,
  mdate: new Date('2017-04-27 11:26:02.147')
});

allocations.push({
  qtA: 95,
  mdata: '1234',
  mid: '234234234',
  qtyToDoTemp: 11,
  mpriority: 1,
  mdate: new Date('2016-10-06 00:00:00.000')
});

allocations.push({
  qtA: 75,
  mdata: '1234',
  mid: '234234234',
  qtyToDoTemp: 11,
  mpriority: 8,
  mdate: new Date('2017-02-20 12:41:34.903')
});

allocations.push({
  qtA: 45,
  mdata: '1234',
  mid: '234234234',
  qtyToDoTemp: 11,
  mpriority: 0,
  mdate: new Date('2017-04-27 11:26:02.147')
});
```

If you're unfamiliar with Javascript and come from a different language, know this: arrays in JS are not like arrays in other languages, they're objects that have special syntax and do their best to behave like arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I recommend maintaining your objects sorted rather than sorting them. Specifically in this case, I suggest achieving this through a representation function `repr` and utilizing a `TrueSet` (refer to the [@ut8pia/classifier](https://github.com/ut8pia/classifier) library).

```
const
    repr = obj => [obj.mpriority, obj.mdate],
    set = new TrueSet(repr)
        .letAll(allocations)
```

This approach offers significant advantages:

- Simplicity in code
- Ability to add additional objects to your collection without disrupting the order
- Ability to query the collection

```
const
    got = set.class(1)
        .which(predicate)
```

The `class(1)` call retrieves all objects associated with the specified `priority=1`. This iteration of objects provides methods for filtering, composing, and transforming the iteration. For example, the `which(predicate)` method narrows down the iteration to objects that fulfill the given predicate.