# how to change the javascript version in firefox browser

Tags: javascript

help -> about firefox shows firefox version 63.0(32 bit)

but my javascript version shows 1.5

http://jsfiddle.net/Ac6CT/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jsver = 1.0;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.1">
  jsver = 1.1;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.2">
  jsver = 1.2;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.3">
  jsver = 1.3;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.4">
  jsver = 1.4;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.5">
  jsver = 1.5;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.6">
  jsver = 1.6;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.7">
  jsver = 1.7;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.8">
  jsver = 1.8;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.9">
  jsver = 1.9;
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  alert(jsver);
</script>
```

I want to use the latest javascript version.

Comment: the `language` attribute on a script element is deprecated - so your code is flawed - javascript on Mozilla supports 98% of ES6, 100% of ES2016, most of ES2017 and 2018

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you read one of the answers over here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/4271566](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271566/how-do-i-know-which-version-of-javascript-im-using), since it matches your code exactly. That answer is 8 years old and out of date. Seeing "1.5" is the expected behavior in the latest version of Firefox.

You can prove this by using a newer feature. For example,

```
const x = 5
x --> 5
```

The const feature was added since "Javascript 1.5," so this serves as evidence for my above claim.

Comment: yes i can use let also, but want to know the version

Comment: You should not rely on the version number, and instead try to determine whether a specific feature is available. This is because browsers don't always implement every feature, even if they implement most.