# How to get JavaScript Socket.IO version?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, flask-socketio

I use [`Flask`](https://github.com/pallets/flask) and [`Flask-SocketIO`](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO) inside of a Python application.

Recently, when I start up the app, I am given this message:

```
The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols (further occurrences of this error will be logged with level INFO)
```

From my searching, I come to [this table](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#version-compatibility) in `Flask-SocketIO`s' docs, which suggests I have version incompatibilities in my system.

**I would like to figure out which version of JavaScript Socket.IO I have.  How can this be done?**

---

**System Details**

If it's not obvious, I am new to JavaScript.

- OS: macOS version 10.15.7
- JavaScript version: 1.7

  - From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4271622/11163122) pointing to [this website](http://jsfiddle.net/Ac6CT/)
- Browser: Google Chrome version 87.0.4280.88
- Python version: 3.8.6
- Packages from Python virtual environment:

```
Flask                                     1.1.2
Flask-SocketIO                            5.0.1
python-engineio                           4.0.0
python-socketio                           5.0.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conflict is probably from using different protocol revisions on the client and the server.

From [socket.io Client API](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/index.html#io-protocol):

> The protocol defines the format of the packets exchanged between the client and the server. Both the client and the server must use the ***same revision*** in order to understand each other.

To determine the revision number of the client,

From HTML:

```html
<script src="<your-path-to>socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  const socket = io('http://localhost');

  const revisionNumber = socket.protocol;
</script>
```

Or from JavaScript:

```js
const io = require('socket.io-client');
// or with import syntax
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

const revisionNumber = io.protocol;
```

Or from the Flask-SocketIO source code:

1. search for `__version__` in the file `__init__.py`. The line will look like this:

```
__version__ = '5.0.2dev'
```

2. Using that `__version__` value, look up the corresponding Socket.IO protocol revision:

```
+--------------+----------------+
| __version__  |  protocol rev. |
+--------------+----------------+
|    4.x.x     |     3, 4       |
+--------------+----------------+
|    5.x.x     |     5          |
+--------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Okay this will reveal how much of a noob I am.  How can I figure out my path to `socket.io.js` for the HTML code block you posted?

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer @terrymorse, I updated my question with details of my Python virtual environment.  The version of `Flask-SocketIO` I have is `5.0.1`.  However, I was interested in discerning my **JavaScript Socket.IO version**, since that's what I need to match Python with.  You're correct, I am not loading from an HTML file.  How can I get the JavaScript Socket IO version?

Comment: I ran the JavaScript provided in this question after running `npm install socket.io-client`, and was output `5`.  This still doesn't answer my question, I am looking for the JavaScript Socket.IO version, not a client version.  I agree with the quote you have on matching versions, so I need to match the JavaScript Socket.IO version with my client's version.  Also, thank you again for your pointers so far! :)

Comment: I think the "server" in my case is Google Chrome, or is Google Chrome my client? I am using `Flask`, and now this is confusing me.  All I know is I am getting that log message mentioning `unsupported version` when my versions of `Flask-SocketIO`, `python-engineio`, and `python-socketio` all seem to be compatible per the chart, so I was thinking I need to match my system with the version of JavaScript Socket.IO.  Sorry for overcomplicating this answer @terrymorse and thank you for all your help

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer The socet.io client code runs in the browser, the server code runs on a server. See [Socket.IO docs](https://socket.io/docs/v3). Also see this github issue for [python-socketio - The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/issues/578).

Comment: Okay @terrymorse, turns out there was a version of JavaScript Socket.IO embedded in my HTML, version 2.0.4.  I explain in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65649075/11163122), which explicitly discusses the solution.  Thanks again for your patience, and for linking that issue.  Knowing what I know now, your answer makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution.
This is what the head of my index.html file looks like:

```
<title>Chat Room</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.8/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

I found this script from some tutorial on youtube. I am programming on Pycharm and when i left clicked the link in this line:
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`
it opened a popup asking me if i wanted to install the package.

Hope this works for you
to see the javaScript part of the code you can look at my question:
[How do i properly install flask-socketIO?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65646771/13697409)

Comment: Isn't the `socket.io` version shown in your first script tag: `/libs/socket.io/1.4.8/...`?

Comment: Yes also forgot to mention that. It needed to be 3.0.5

Answer (score 1):

You can see the following chart to understand the version compatibility:

[image]

Recently I have tried and tested following versions in my mac and they are totally compatible with each other:

Backend:

```
python-engineio==4.1.0 
python-socketio==5.2.1 
Flask==1.1.2 
Flask-SocketIO==5.0.1
```

Frontend:

```
socket.io-client="^3.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, thanks to the previous two answers to this question, I finally figured out how to identify the version of JavaScript Socket.IO.

The underlying reason I couldn't figure out faster was:

- I inherited this code base, so I didn't really what it imported where
- I don't really know `Flask`

The version of JavaScript Socket.IO was called out within `layout.html` in the templates directory (see [`Flask` docs here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/templateinheritance/#base-template)).  Within the `<head>` element, the `socket.io.js` script is embedded:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
```

It clearly calls out the **version of JavaScript Socket.IO to be 2.0.4**.

So, per `Flask-SocketIO`'s [version compatibility table](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#version-compatibility) and [this comment on a `Flask-SocketIO` issue](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/issues/578#issuecomment-742477016), I will now just pin `Flask-SocketIO` in my package's requirements like so: `Flask-SocketIO>=4.3.2,<5`.

Since this answer is to *my* use case, and not generic, I will not be accepting as the answer.