# How do i properly install flask-socketIO?

Tags: sockets, flask, flask-socketio, python-sockets, flask-sockets

I have installed multiple times Flask-socketio on my mac, closely reading the instructions and installing the requirements (eventlet/gevent). Athough when i run my simple code to test, it either says that i have not imported the modules or show nothing until i open index.html in my browser where it then displays :
`The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols (further occurrences of this error will be logged with level INFO)`

Here is my app.py code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'hello'
    
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='*')
@socketio.on('message')
def handle(msg):
    print("message: "+msg)
    send(msg, bradcast=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

And here is my terminal window:
[image]

Here is my index.html code (if needed):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Chat Room</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.8/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000');

    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.send('User has connected!');
    });

    socket.on('message', function(msg) {
        $("#messages").append('<li>'+msg+'</li>');
        console.log('Received message');
    });

    $('#sendbutton').on('click', function() {
        socket.send($('#myMessage').val());
        $('#myMessage').val('');
    });

});
</script>
<ul id="messages"></ul>
<input type="text" id="myMessage">
<button id="sendbutton">Send</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [the Flask-SocketIO docs](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for information about version compatibility.

You have installed Flask-SocketIO version 5, so you need version 3 of the JavaScript client, but you have 1.4.8.

Use this CDN URL instead for version 3.0.5: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.0.5/socket.io.min.js

Comment: I looked in the python interpreter on pycharm and shows that  FlaskSocketIO is version : 5.0.1 . How do install js socket client with the link?

Comment: You don't install it - you're already referencing it in the `<script>` tag in your index.html. Just update the tag to refer to the new version by changing the version number.